# How do I keep this sidebar stationary yet still responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, sidebar

I am currently practicing creating *responsive* websites.

I have a problem with the side bar on this website,

I don't believe I know how to correctly position this,

and I also don't know how to keep it from moving down when the screen width size decreases.

How can I fix this?

I have such a hard time posting code, I can't seem to get it to work past the first line or two.

I added a jsFiddle with all of the code. I made a comment where the sidebar, 
**.other**, in my css code.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwn69/

css :

```
/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, i woudnt rely on properties like 'float'. They're tricky and can get a lot of repaints in some cases, which slows down your application.

To make what you wanted, i had to change de .focus and the .other classes

```
.focus {
    width:66.00625%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*    844.8px / 1280 */
    background-color: #3d3c3c;
}
.other {
    width: 30.99375%;   
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    /*    1.5% allowed on each side*/
    background-color: #3d3c3c;
}
```

I must also warn you that responsive design isn't about doing a couple of css rules that works under every condition/screen-size. With a little more CSSing, you'll get this page looks better and eventually it will be useable on any device. But, for example, mobile apps doens't have a menu like the one you're building. It uses drawer menus and other things to show links, because their space is limited.

While you can achieve to show these contents on a very a huge screen or a very tiny, it isn't enought because every device has it's own better way to show your UI components.

So, i'd suggest you read about [media-queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). They're usefull to make specific CSS rules for devices that fit a certain condition.

Then, i'd suggest you learn how to [positions](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) work in CSS

Heres your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwn69/5/)

Comment: I Appreciate the depth of this reply. Thanks